# Google Chrome extension autoupdate

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am using direct upload to Google Chrome Store via Webstore Developer Dashboard. I uploaded yesterday and it was published at night. This morning my colleague switched on his mac, opened Chrome, waited for 20 minutes, but extension was not updated. I did the same and my extension was updated.

What can it be? Are there any tweaks to make installed extension be up-to-date instantly? We do not want our users to use different versions of our extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a period of a few hours to a week where users could be using the old version of your extension. There isn't really anything you can do about it.

Comment: I couldn't find any reliable source, where it is written. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate this link says just "ignore that page if you use dashboard". Is there any article around that says that it takes few hours to week?

Comment: This is the timeframe I've experienced over the last couple of years publishing a dozen extensions. It's under 24 hours for most users but there are frequently a few that lag.